# How to make a required field be invisible if valid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, required

I have this kind of html:

```
<form method="post" action="register">
    <input type="text" name="name" required />
    <button>Next</button>
</form>
```

When I click the Next button, I want to hide the Name field, but only if it is valid(not empty) and I don't want to submit the form. How can I do this with plain JavaScript?

If you know a way with jQuery, please write that too. Thanks.

Comment: I know that the browser validates the form on submit for required fields automatically (it checks if they are empty or not). I want to call this function on my own and I have no idea how I can do this, so I haven't tried anything. I don't want to check if the field is empty on my own, I want the browser to check.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    if ($('input[name=name]').val() != '') {
        $('input[name=name]').fadeOut(); // Or hide, or css('display', 'none')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you will change "form button" for the **ID of the button**, and "form input" for the **ID of the input**. The jQuery code would be something like this:

```
$("form button").click(function() {
    if ($("form input").val() != "")
        $("form input").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
var check = $('#name').val();
if (check == '') {
    $('#name').hide();
}
})
```

If the input has no content, it will be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Make class e.g. "validate", which you can attach to your form after clicking Next.

Then in CSS:

```
.validate input:valid {
     display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `onsubmit` event:

```js
var validate = function(form) {
  var toSubmit = true;
  if (form.name.value) { //has some text
    form.name.style.display = "none"; //hide the input field
  } else {
    toSubmit = false;
  }
  return toSubmit;
};
```

```html
<form method="post" action="register" onsubmit='return validate(this);'>
  <input type="text" name="name" required />
  <button>Next</button>
</form>
```

**EDIT**

Try `blur` event:

```js
var validate = function(box) {
  if (!box.value) {
    alert('This field is required');
    box.focus();
  }
};
```

```html
<form method="post" action="register">
  <input type="text" name="name" onblur='validate(this);' />
  <button>Next</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to call the browser functionality for checking if the required field is empty? I know that if you click submit, and a required field is empty, the browser will notify you about that and I want to use this functionality, and not my own function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form method="post" action="register">

    <div id="steps1">
        <input id="txtname" type="text" placeholder="enter name here" name="name" />
        <input id="btnNext" type="button" value="next" />
    </div>
    <div id="complete" style="display:none;">
         <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="enter age here"  />
         <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </div>
</form>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnNext").click(function () {
        if ($("#txtname").val() != "") {
            $("#steps1").hide();
            $("#complete").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var input = e.target.firstElementChild;
    
    if(!input.validity.valueMissing) {
        input.style.display = 'none';
    }
}, false);
```

```html
<form method="post" action="register">
    <input type="text" name="name" required />
    <button>Next</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read these to understand the code and why.

[`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

[`EventTarget.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

[`onsubmit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onsubmit)

[`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)

[`Constraint validation HTML5`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/)

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var input = e.target.firstElementChild;
    
    if(!input.validity.valueMissing) {
        input.style.display = 'none';
    }
}, false);
```

```html
<form method="post" action="register">
    <input type="text" name="name" required />
    <button>Next</button>
</form>
```